# deleting just the parent node and not the child node in json object

Tags: javascript, json

```
{"0":
     {"id":"1",
      "Name":"A1",
      "parent_id":"0"},
 "1":
    {"id":"2",
     "Name":"A2",
     "parent_id":"0",
     "0":
         {"id":"3",
          "Name":"A3",
          "parent_id":"2",
          "0": 
              {"id":"4",
               "Name":"A4",
               "parent_id":"3"}}}}
```

This is populated from a database table. I want to delete only node id 2(A2). Id 3's parent id should automatically become id 1. That is A2's immediate child becomes the child of it's parent along with its children. I cannot use splice or remove on this as I am using js with QML. Any suggestions? I am currently able to delete the entire node along with its children(a2,a3,a4) by finding the node that has to be deleted and assigning it to null.I am having a difficulty in deleting just the selected node and not its children.

Comment: You have to copy (clone?) and reattach the node. No other way around it (that I know of).

Comment: lets say I do get a clone of the children nodes using a find_node function. When I re-assign the tree to the childnode directly, nothing happens. I dont see any change.

Answer (score 2):

`jsonObject['1'] = jsonObject['1']['0'];`

This *should* decrement the ref count for A2 and kill it but increment the ref count for A3, saving A3 and its children.

Comment: I think that would work. I will try that. What if jsonObject['1']['0'] has a sibling jsonObject['1']['1']. How would I traverse and attach that?

Comment: @sandy: Then you're back to my answer.  You probably want to change the structure of the data and use a function to pull the current view when needed.

Comment: I agree with John that with that structural difference you'll probably want to write a small utility function to do what you really want.

Answer (score 1):

You can't simply delete.  You need to copy the content you want to keep before deleting.

Maybe your real problem is the structure of the data itself.  Most likely, you want the json structure to be flat, then use a function to recreate the tree as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do something similar to this and unfortunately, the only way I found to do it was to rebuild the JSON structure manually.  :(